# Creating 1 Customer Control with Textbox and PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, webforms, custom-controls, winforms-to-web

I want to create a custom control where a textbox will be over a picturebox. I have search but cant find the answer. I have encountered create your own button, dropbox, textbox, etc that will do specific action. I want to basically combine both controllers (textbox and picturebox with predefined attributes) into one. I am not sure if this can be done. I want this custom control to be in a library class where I can drag and drop from the toolbox into a winform or webform.

Comment: Sounds like a plan.  You can do it!

Comment: You must create a user control ? Search for how create user control codeproject?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/88326/A-Simple-User-Control

Comment: I hope you don't want the TextBox to be transparent. Other than that: Go for it!

Comment: Thank that really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add new Class library project to your solution :

On Solution Explorer right click , select Add ,New Project . Select Class Library ,Click OK

And add user control to this new Class library :

On class library , right click and select Add, User control ,insert a name click OK

Now drag textBox and picturebox on user control . Build your project.

Now you can add your new user control from Toolbox to your form